# Long-running JavaScript Web

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I am making a website that contains html5 and JavaScript,
The website requires very few user interactions (only at the start),
after that the web will display all kind of informations (text, time, pictures, etc)

In the website I always use timer (setInterval) at specified intervals (3seconds or even 20seconds), For the first 2 hours, it runs fine, after that, sometimes it will crash the browser or make it hang, Now I wonder if using setInterval is a good idea

I always clear the interval (with clearInterval) if I want to change the interval then activate it again. I need the web to run days or even weeks, sometimes if it's not hang, it will cause the browser(not the whole PC) to run very slow,

so is it actually a good idea to use setInterval and clearInterval in the long run?
Or should I switch to setTimeout instead (or will they be the same)?

If the cause is memory leak, could this be the cause?

```
var element=document.getElementById("image1"); //it is DIV element
var image=new Image(); 
image.src=url;  // url is a path to a specific image(blob or external source)
image.onload=function(){
//basically
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
element.style.width=image.width.toString()+"px"; //set the original size
element.style.height=image.height.toString()+"px";
 //by the end of this function I don't clear the variable image like image=null
};
```

Comment: I guess that you have a memory leak somewhere in your source code... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970525/how-to-find-js-memory-leaks

Comment: For instance will this get thrown to the GC? `var a = {}; var b = {a: a}; a.b = b;`

Comment: Executing Javascript over a whole week is not a good idea, imo. That sounds like restarting your pc only once every week. Try to reload the page after an hour and restore the last status. That would be my approach

Comment: @Fuzzyma: [Gmail does it as well](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/memory/effectivemanagement/)

Comment: How large is the DOM getting over this time?  Are things getting replaced or appended over time?

Comment: it's getting replaced over time with different (or sometimes the same) pictures

Comment: Would it be possible for us to see some more of the source then?  Some of "//some code to display the url in a DIV or IMG inside the DOM tree" might be helpful for example.

Comment: done, it's edited in the question

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
Apparently it was not because of the image and DOM creation as I was always handle them correctly after a closure,
It was because after some changing of certain DOM Element, I always attach event-handler to an object with jquery ($(element).bind(eventhandler,theHandler);)

I thought when I attach the event with bind, it will replace the handler, but apparently it will stack all og the handlers attached with the new one. So now, I do it only once or unbind the old one if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there shouldn't be any problems with `setInterval`, but i guess that you have a memory leak in your source code:

[Check this thread to find tools to help you debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970525/how-to-find-js-memory-leaks)

Does this go to the GC?

```
var a = {}; 
var b = {a: a}; 
a.b = b;
```

Or this:

```
var a = function(b) { 
    var c = function(b) {}; 
    c(b); 
}
var b = {}; // <-- what about this object?
a(b);
```

Maybe you should start rethinking if its a good idea to have a browser running for multiply weeks maybe you should start looking at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)?

Comment: Of course those will be garbage-collected once `a` and `b` go out of scope. What do you think?

Comment: will this cause the memory leak?
var image=new Image();
image.src=url --> path to a specific image(blob or external source)
image.onload=function(){
//some code to display the url in a DIV or IMG inside the DOM tree
//by the end of this function I don't clear the variable image like image=null
};

those codes above are the ones that repeated every interval specified in the callback of the setInterval

will that be the cause of memory leak?