# javascript memory leak detector

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, gwt, memory-leaks

We have developed web application in gwt. Our application got hang up after 4 hours showing "website is not responding".

Environment:

32 bit Internet Explorer 9
GWT 2.4
64 bit Windows Enterprise Edition 7 
Eclipse Indigo 32 bit
Java 32 bit

I there any tool which exactly shows where the memory leak is happening in front end javascript code
(as GWT converts java codes to javascript codes) so that we can analyze javascript code and track back 
our handwritten GWT java code and do the necessary fix. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry, these should be as below,                                                           32 bit Internet Explorer 9, GWT 2.4, 64 bit Windows Enterprise Edition 7, Eclipse Indigo 32 bit, Java 32 bit.

Comment: There are a lot known memory leaks when working with IE. You should update your GWT version first. Some of this leaks are already solved with GWT 2.7.

Comment: Did u tried this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gpde/2009/08/03/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2/ and also read these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970525/how-to-find-js-memory-leaks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621074/finding-javascript-memory-leaks-with-chrome